# Java Mongo db 'and' operator

Tags: mongodb

```
final Bson filter = and(in(ROUTEID_KEY, routeIds), or(ne(DELETED_KEY, TRUE), exists(DELETED_KEY, FALSE)));
final FindIterable<Document> doc = someCollection.find(filter);
```

I am relatively new to mongodb. can some one please explain me this filter condition.I think it means all documents with given '**routeIds**' as well as all documents having **DELETED_KEY** field value as false along with all documets where '**DELETED_KEY**' field don't exist. But when i am running *find()* for below filter only, unexpectedly i am getting more values.

```
 final Bson filter = and(in(ROUTEID_KEY, routeIds));
```

Please explain what the 1st filter condition actually means.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with java driver and this exact api, but I'm relatively sure that it means "select all document which a) have ROUTEID_KEY value from this list and b) don't have their DELETED_KEY set to TRUE or don't have DELETED_KEY at all".

The second part (the `or`) reduces the returned dataset, it does not add to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped